Issues Receiving Button Press Events from Bluetooth Button (Jieli-Tech ATG-SJL, iOS)
I’m working on an iOS app that connects to a Bluetooth button device (ATG-SJL) using CoreBluetooth. The device uses a chipset from Jieli-Tech, and I’m trying to listen for button press events (single click, double click, long press) via the characteristic UUID AE42.
The device connects successfully, and I’m able to discover services and characteristics. However, I’m facing issues in receiving notifications for button press events.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Connected to the device and discovered the AE42 characteristic.

Setup notifications for the AE42 characteristic.

Defined a few patterns to detect single clicks, double clicks, and long presses based on the data received from the characteristic.


Here’s a snippet of the relevant code:
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
    for characteristic in characteristics {
        if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "AE42" {
            ae42Characteristic = characteristic
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            print("Notifications enabled for AE42 characteristic")
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error updating value for characteristic \(characteristic.uuid): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    guard let value = characteristic.value else {
        print("No value received for characteristic \(characteristic.uuid)")
        return
    }
    
    print("Value received for characteristic: \(characteristic.uuid), value: \(value.hexEncodedString())")
    
    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "AE42" {
        processInputReport(value)
    }
}

The processInputReport function looks for specific patterns in the data received:
private func processInputReport(_ data: Data) {
    inputBuffer.append(data)
    
    // Check for button interactions like single click, double click, long press
    if checkForSingleClick() {
        handleClick()
        inputBuffer.removeAll()
    } else if checkForDoubleClick() {
        handleDoubleClick()
        inputBuffer.removeAll()
    } else if checkForLongPress() {
        handleLongPress()
        inputBuffer.removeAll()
    }

    if inputBuffer.count > 20 {
        inputBuffer.removeAll()
    }
}

The issue:
The device connects successfully, but the button press events are either not consistently received, or they come in unpredictable patterns.
I’ve confirmed that notifications are enabled, and I see some data, but it doesn’t always match the expected patterns for single, double, or long presses.
Additionally, I'm unsure whether I'm handling the characteristic data processing correctly, or if there’s a specific issue related to how this Bluetooth chip sends input events.
Sspecs:

Device: ATG-SJL (Jieli-Tech Bluetooth Chipset)
iOS Version: 16.x
xCode 15.4
Library/SDK: CoreBluetooth
Jieli-Tech GitHub Repository: iOS-JL_Bluetooth

What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the device is connected and the characteristic notifications are enabled.
Used a Bluetooth scanner to confirm that the characteristic UUIDs match and that the AE42 characteristic is used for button press events.
Implemented pattern matching for different types of button presses (single, double, long press), but the data doesn’t always align with my expectations.

Questions:

Are there any specific nuances with Jieli-Tech devices when handling characteristic notifications that I’m missing?
Is there a better approach to processing characteristic data for detecting button interactions?
Has anyone had success receiving consistent notifications from Jieli-Tech Bluetooth devices on iOS?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
ps : I did find a thread where someone managed to connect using a ESP -
https://community.platformio.org/t/how-can-i-control-an-esp32-with-a-tiktok-bluetooth-controller/41927/5
